# Regular Expression to get all characters before "_" and after "-"

Tags: c#

I want to get `"FileType"` using a Regular Expression.

Here is a example string:

> randomname-id-mininthostname-**FileType**_20221118.zip

I tried `(?=-).*(?<=_)` but it will return `"-minint-FileType_"`

Answer (score 2):

Replace `.*` which stands for any number of any character by `[^-]*` which stands for any number of any character except `-`. Or even better, since we want to capture at least one characxter: `[^-]+`.

You inverted lookahead and lookbehind. I corrected that as well.

```
(?<=-)[^-]+(?=_)
```

Comment: The lookbehind (or a capturing group, etc.) is required if they want to make sure FileType only occurs after a `-`. The negative character class could also be `[^-_]` if the OP always wants the first underscore to be the delimiter.